# Error adding slots using lambdas (Boost Signals2)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++17, boost-signals2

The code below prints `worldworld` to the console rather than `hello world`. I can fix this by changing `sig.connect([&]() { slot(); });` to `sig.connect(slot)`, but don't understand why. What's happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

void add_slot(boost::signals2::signal<void()> &sig,
              std::function<void()> slot) {
  sig.connect([&]() { slot(); });
}

int main() {
  boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig;
  add_slot(sig, []() {
    std::cout << "hello ";
  });
  add_slot(sig, []() {
    std::cout << "world";
  });
  sig();
}
```

Comment: You're capturing `slot` by reference, but it dies at the end of `add_slot`. You need to capture it by value, for example with `[=]` or `[slot = std::move(slot)]`.

Comment: Ah. Thank you so much for pointing this out.